# Proving that $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ if $f'(x) \gt K \gt 0 \forall x$...

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, solution-verification

I would appreciate a review or a different approach:

The question: Prove that if $f$ is derivable for $x \gt a$, and there exists $0 \lt K \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x) \gt K \forall x \gt a$, then $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$  as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

My proof: Let $f$ be a derivable (thus continuous) function for $x \gt a$, and let $0 \lt K$ be a real number such that $f'(x) \gt K$ for all x's in the mentioned domain.
According to the "Lagrange theorem" we can say that, for every $x$ in the domain and every $c \in (a,x)$ the following is true:
$$\frac{(f(x)-f(a))}{x-a} = f'(c) \gt K \implies f(x) \gt Kx - Ka + f(a).$$
Both $f(a)$ and $-Ka$ are constants. In order to complete our proof, we must show that for every $M\gt0$, there is $m\gt0$, such that for every $x\gt m: f(x)> M$:
Let $M>0$. We'll choose $m = \frac{M+Ka-f(a)}{K}$, and see that for every $x\gt m:$
$$f(x) > Kx - Ka + f(a) > Km - Ka + f(a) = M.$$
Just as required.

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: wouldn't $f(x) = 2x-\lim_{t \to \min \{a, x\}} \frac{1}{t-a}$ be some kind of exception to this? I'd say it has $f'(x) = 2 >1\forall x>a$ but $f(x) \not\to\infty$. Obviously this depends on convention since one could just as easily state that the derivative cannot exist when the function itself does not.

Answer (score 1):

Just one observation:

If $x>m=\frac{M+Ka−f(a)}{K}$ is not neccesary true that $x>a$, so the inequality $f(x)>Kx−Ka+f(a)$ is not justified. But if you choose $m=\max\{\frac{M+Ka−f(a)}{K},a\}$, all your inequalities are true.